# iOS 11 - persistent banner notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification, ios11

iOS 11 has a new feature: persistent banner notifications. You can select this option via the settings menu -> specific app settings -> notifications.

Is there a way to use these persistent banners by default for a specific app I develop? Some configuration in the plist file?

I've seen Google calendar has achieved something like this.

I didn't find any documentation about this matter.

Comment: Any news about this?